# How to switch to app or start app on key press?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, productivity

I'd like to reach some programs (firefox, gnome terminal, intellij) on a specific keypress ; or start it if it is not started.

I tried to bind some gnome custom shortcut (with an obscure binding like ctrl + ~, which my keyboard can produce with  single key strike, thanks to the qmk firmware) to some custom command (jumpapp), but it doesn't work and I don't even know where to find an error logs

How can you switch to or run an app (or execute a command) with a single keypress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>[Number]</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).

Add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to open a new window.

The numbers are in the respective order of icons in the dock. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> will reveal the numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just make a gnome shortcut key to launch it.

super, keyboard shortcuts, scroll to bottom, + to make one, name it, type the app name, set your keystroke.